# Django import-export: only export

Tags: django, django-import-export

I'm using the third party library [Django-import-export](https://django-import-export.readthedocs.org/en/latest/#) for importing/exporting data.

It's working properly but I only want the *export* functionality (not import one).

How could I use only *export* without *import*?

Comment: This is not a question.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

```
from import_export.admin import ExportMixin

class BookAdmin(ExportMixin, admin.ModelAdmin):
```

Comment: Just in case someone runs into my same mistake, the order in which you inherit the ExportMixin is relevant (first the mixing, then the modeladmin, just as indicated by user2947136). For some reason i was writing it in reverse and wasn't working.

Comment: Just in case someone has the same confusion as I had: `admin.ModelAdmin` is a subclass of `django.contrib` or, in full, `django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin` and not a subclass of `import_export.admin`: See [here](https://django-import-export.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api_admin.html?highlight=ModelAdmin#import_export.admin.ExportMixin).

Comment: Additional FYI, ExportMixin comes from here `from import_export.admin import ExportMixin`

Answer (score 5):

If you want the action of `Export Selected Books`, you can use

```
class BookAdmin(ExportActionModelAdmin,admin.ModelAdmin):
```

Answer (score 2):

As your question is not really described, I can only guess, that you want to remove the "import" button in the Admin view?

As described [here](https://django-import-export.readthedocs.org/en/latest/getting_started.html#admin-integration) you have to set the ExportMixin on your ModelAdmin. So it looks something like this

```
class BookAdmin(ExportMixin, ModelAdmin):
```